# How to create a values folder for specific device width

Tags: android

How do I create a specific *res values* folder for different device resolutions, and how can I identify that this device comes under a specific category of density.

Comment: "How to create values folder for specific width device" -- you don't. You can create a `values` folder for a certain device width *or larger*. Use `res/values-wNNNdp/` or `res/values-swNNNdp/`, where `NNN` is the width in device-independent pixels (`dp`). The difference between the two is that `-wNNNdp` will be used if the *current* width of the device (in its current orientation) is that size or larger, while `-swNNNdp` will be used if the *smallest* width (in either orientation) is that size or larger.

Answer (score 0):

In Android Studio when u create any resource file there is options called available qualifier in that use size qualifier and click on add after u can select option or u can use Smallest Screen Width or Screen Width or Screen Height for creating specific resource file for specific device resolution.

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this link to create apps for different screen sizes.
https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html